# How to Visualize Python / Jupyter Notebook Results in a Web Site/Web Page or Dashboard?

Tags: python, php, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to execute a python file using real user inputs from Web page Form and output should be displayed in the same Web Page or Web Dashboard. I have now created the Python file as .py and ipynb formats. But now I want to take the user inputs to the python code from HTML form and after executing the code results should be displayed as a HTML format using a Web Page. What should I do to achieve this target? I don't know any way to link python  file and HTML easily. If anyone have an idea regarding this please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

A way to make the jupyter notebook interactive and to take the user inputs into account when running the code in the cells of the notebook is to use [Jupyter Widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Thanks to the widgets, you will be able to bind the value of some variables to some actions made by the users. For example, you can bind the value of a variable to a text input the user will fill. That way, you can create a form, or can even think of using slider, dropdown lists, etc. to collect the information needed and to run the code accordingly.

Then, you can convert your jupyter notebook to a dashboard through the use of some tools such as [Voila](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Also, you can make the jupyter notebook publicly available thanks to some service such as [Binder](https://mybinder.org/) (and associated [documentation](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), that makes it available through an url and running the notebook on their server. You can also think of running the jupyter notebook on your own server and to share the associated url to the users.

Those are some tools that are based on directly using the jupyter notebook without creating and coding any classical html web page on your own. Yet, if you intend to code your form in a specific html web page, those tools will not help unfortunately as they aim to "do that job for you".

Comment: @user12760080 , all the examples at [the Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/) run via MyBinder and so you can combine Jnsll's suggestions. And there's other dashboard options out there. Using a notebook in some form is the easiest presently, however I'll mention for completeness sake there are other ways. It used to be done more traditionally with Python and web server frameworks. PythonAnywhere offers a [flask tutorial](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/). I've heard of folks using Python on Glitch, see [here](https://support.glitch.com/t/how-to-use-python-on-glitch/11201/6).